# Visualising the decision tree in sklearn

Tags: python, tree, jupyter-notebook, sklearn-pandas

When I want to visualise the tree I got this error.

I have shown the required libraries imported. Is there expected reason with jupiter-notebook ?

```
from sklearn import tree
import matplotlib.pyplot
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
cancer=load_breast_cancer()
x=cancer.data
y=cancer.target
clf=DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1000)
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y)
clf=clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
tree.plot_tree(clf.fit(x_train,y_train))
```

> AttributeError: module 'sklearn.tree' has no attribute 'plot_tree'

Comment: check it out here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html

Comment: make sure your `matplotlib` version is >= 1.5 and try to save your fit to an object before putting it in the plot function

Comment: matplotlib version is 3.0.3

Comment: `plot_tree` is new in version 0.21. Maybe check your scikit-learn version

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was the version of my  sklearn

Answer (score 8):

I assigned the tree to an object and added `plt.show()`. This works for me.

```
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn import tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
cancer = load_breast_cancer()
x = cancer.data
y = cancer.target
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 1000)
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y)

fig = clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
tree.plot_tree(fig)
plt.show()
```

But I recommend using `graphviz`, it's much more flexible.

Comment: current version is 0.21.3
you can upgrade running `!pip install -U scikit-learn` or `conda upgrade scikit-learn` if you are using anaconda

Comment: Thank you so much, I have got it after upgrading

Comment: This is not an answer. You are just saying "I don't have this problem".

Answer (score 4):

upgrade **sklearn** package:

```
pip install --upgrade sklearn
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `plot_tree` is new is `sklearn` version 0.21, as indicated in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html). Check if you have a version sufficient by running this:

```
import sklearn

print(sklearn.__version__)

assert float(sklearn.__version__[2:]) >= 21, 'sklearn version insufficient.'
```

If you get an error message, you need to update `sklearn`

```
pip install --upgrade sklearn
```

Answer (score 1):

Because plot_tree is defined after sklearn version 0.21

For checking Version
Open any python idle
Running below program.

```
import sklearn
print (sklearn.__version__)
```

If the version shows less than 0.21 then you need to upgrade the sklearn library.

Open Anaconda prompt and write below command

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```